# Compiler Error : com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy$1 not found

Tags: java, scala, maven, compiler-errors, akka

I am using JDK8 with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1 (tried it on my Win x64 - java version 1.8.0_92-windows-x64)

I have big multi-module Maven project.
I am launching Maven goal "clean package" from a main module with packaging type "pom" and everything is OK. Maven shows me "BUILD SUCCESS"
But when I'm trying to run project it shows me line of text that can't be clicked:

*"Compiler Error : com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class    file for akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy$1 not found"*

I have tried everything possible - in every class that uses Supervisor strategy's methods i added 
*import static akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.start* and etc.
but no success.

Any hints or anyone experienced this kind of behavior as well? I think This appears to be due some class is being missed in my classpath but anyway I don't know how to solve this problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Community **2017.2** version of IntelliJ changing compiler from `Javac` to `Eclipse` solved the problem

`Settings -> Build, Exec.. -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Use Compiler : Eclipse`

Answer (score 1):

When I get this problem, most of the time it is because I'm doing a static import of a Scala object function in my Java code.
Maven seems to compile it fine, but IntelliJ does not seem to like it for whatever reason.
So if you are doing this (or anyone else reading this), remove the static import and call the object's function directly from the Object.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a pom problem with overlapping dependencies.

In IDEA, open your pom file, press ctrl+alt+shift+U. From that window, everything that is supersed as a dependency (red), click on it and press shift+delete.

That will exclude the dependency from your pom. If you do it right it should solve dependency issues 90% of the times